# error when unserialize the serialize data

Tags: php, serialization

serialize data is

```
      a:8:{s:10:"First_Name";s:6:"harish";s:9:"Last_Name";s:5:"verma";
s:5:"Email";s:16:"harish@facebook.com";s:7:"Address";s:6:"jaipur";s:4:"City";s:6:"Jaipur";s:5:"State";
    s:9:"Rajasthan";s:12:"Country_Name";s:5:"India";s:7:"Cell_No";s:10:"8787878787";}
```

it return true when we change Email to `harish@gmail.com` .... please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: `harish@gmail.com` OR `harish@facebook.com` ?? confusing... what actaully are you trying to do ??

Comment: @bipen when we use harish@facebook.com it return false ... when we change it to harish@gmail.com it return true.

Comment: Need more information, The question is not clear. What returns true and false?

Comment: `harish@facebook.com` should be `s:19`, not `s:16`: please don't tell me you're editing serialized data by hand!

Comment: @MarkBaker yes you are rite . thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice in the serialized data you have this section defining the email address

```
s:16:"harish@facebook.com";
```

Thats says this field is a string of 16 characters. **The string in the field is NOT 16 characters** its **19 characters**

So I guess you are manually fiddling with the data after is has been properly **serialize()'d**

If you are going to manually mess with the serialized data you also have to make it all add up. So either stop manually editing it and re **serialize()** the data properly OR **remember to also change the size parameter data** to match your edits.